# Python Pandas pd.date_range() rounding to next available week start - need previous

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dates and times generating a dataframe:

```
ts = pd.Timestamp('2014-07-01 07:15:11')
te = pd.Timestamp('2014-12-31 12:00:00')

df_weeks = pd.date_range(ts, te, freq='W').to_frame(name='Week')
```

While this is providing weekly intervals as desired, the first week (index 0 in the dataframe) is starting at 2014-07-06 07:15:11, which is the next Sunday in the future.  Instead, I want 2014-06-29 to be my starting interval.  I have attempted using Week.rollback and offsets, but they appear to be providing a number of days which I can then use in a further operation.  I am aware I could calculate this in a function then pass it in, however, I would prefer a solution where this can be handled or elegantly nested in the dataframe.  Is there a way this can be accomplished?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, what you can do is using `dayofweek` of ts and use `pd.Offset` calculated automatically from this date to the last sunday (that is number 6) like:

```
df_weeks = pd.date_range(ts - pd.DateOffset(days=(ts.dayofweek-6)%7), 
                         te, freq='W').to_frame(name='Week')
print (df_weeks.head())
                                   Week
2014-06-29 07:15:11 2014-06-29 07:15:11
2014-07-06 07:15:11 2014-07-06 07:15:11
2014-07-13 07:15:11 2014-07-13 07:15:11
2014-07-20 07:15:11 2014-07-20 07:15:11
2014-07-27 07:15:11 2014-07-27 07:15:11
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help you, I think you can handle it with à datetime logic as basé on weekday:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.weekday.html

```
nbDays_offset= 6- ts.weekday() 
ts=ts+pd.Timedelta(nbDays_offset, unit='d')
```